# Apache Kafka: bootstrap-server is not a recognized option

Tags: networking, apache-kafka, centos

I'm trying to set up Apache Kafka to communicate between two virtual machines running CentOS on the same network. I originally set up a Kafka producer and consumer on one machine and everything was running smoothly. I then set up Kafka on the other machine and in the process of trying to get them to connect, I get the error "bootstrap-server is not a recognized option" (I'm running the most recent version of Kafka, 2.2).

This is what I used to attempt a producer connection:

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server 10.0.0.11:9092 --topic test`

And on the consumer side:

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server 10.0.0.11:9092 --topic test`

The `10.0.0.11` machine is running the server itself.

Comment: It's not until Kafka 2.5.0, console producer accepts `--bootstrap-server`, before this version, use `--broker-list`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According do Apache Kafka Documentation, that can be found here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_send, you should use `--broker-list` property to pass broker address.

Command will be:
`./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test`

**EDIT**

From Apache Kafka **2.5** both options are supported `--broker-list` and `--bootstrap-server`. Suggested one is `--bootstrap-server`

Comment: On the consumer side, it tells me "--broker-list is not a recognized option"

Comment: @AbigailFox, for consumer is `--bootstrap-server`, for producer: `--broker-list`

Comment: my consumer gives me the bootstrap-server error as well. broker-list fixes it for the producer side, but the consumer side still does not work

Comment: It's in the question

Comment: @AbigailFox In the question there is only producer side, that should work after changing property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193049/discussion-between-wardziniak-and-abigail-fox).

Comment: If the brokers are on remote machines, the advertised listeners property would need fixing

Comment: @BartoszWardziński Kakfa official quick start wiki is still '> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
'

Comment: @FullStackDeveloper, From version 2.5 option `--broker-list` is deprecated, and suggestion option is `--bootsrap-server`. For previous version `--broker-list` should be used

Comment: @BartoszWardziński But this tutorial should mention this: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Answer (score 7):

Following command should work.

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Answer (score 1):

./kafka-console-consumer.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic fred

Simply giving this command worked. However in upcoming major release using the option bootstrap-server will be mandatory.

When I use the above command it gives a warning: "Using the ConsoleConsumer with old consumer is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using the new consumer by passing [bootstrap-server] instead of [zookeeper]."